# Pyglet Module not found despite being installed

Tags: python, module, apple-m1, pyglet, modulenotfounderror

I am working on an M1 Mac with Python version 3.9.7. I used pip to install pyglet (1.5.21), which worked.
However when trying to import pyglet in python scripts, the following error pops up:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyglet'`

I also tried installing pyglet version 1.5.16 using conda which results in the same error.

Other packages work just fine.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I also have M1 mac. Try using pip3 instead of pip to install pyglet. Could be you only have pip installed for python3 (which is pip3)

I was having errors with Python not finding the module/attributes -  I resolved it by downloading the pyglet zip from github and saving it to the same folder that my .py file is in.